# Can't parse a date from an excel file using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

```
Data:Panda Dataframe, read from excel

Month      Sales
01-01-17    1009
01-02-17    1004
..
01-12-19    2244

Code:

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
import datetime

CHI = pd.read_excel('D:\DS\TS.xls', index="Month")
CHI['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(CHI['Month']).dt.date
CHI['NetSalesUSD'] = pd.to_numeric(CHI['NetSalesUSD'], errors='coerce')
result = adfuller(CHI)
```

Error received:
float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.date'

I tried converting to integer , still not able to get the results, any suggestions?

Comment: **Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.** _I tried converting the column to date format="%d%m/%Y", but didn't work out_ That error message seems rather clear to me, no? You're going to have to be more specific about what the issue is.

Comment: Well I have clearly given the error msgs and Data above along with the code I tired, can you be more specific what do you need here?

Comment: Excel files are not very straightforward, just pasting some values as they appear on the screen at that particular time does not give us an accurate representation of the data. _can you be more specific what do you need here?_ As I said in my previous comment, it isn’t obvious what the actually issue is. That error message seems extremely clear, and as such we have no idea what part you’re struggling with.

Comment: I saw you edited your post, is the other issue fixed? As before, we need the entire error. _I tried converting to integer_ Why, what for?

Comment: edited the post per your comments, given complete code, I rectified issue from excel it self, but post rectification, while running ADF test, ran into the error mentioned in the description section. DF is of pandas.core.frame.DataFrame type, columns are of pandas.core.series.Series type, let me know, if you need any further info

Comment: _given complete code_ Don’t worry, we don’t need the entire thing, just a [mcve]. _I rectified issue from excel it self_ How? _but post rectification..._ This sounds like an entirely new/different issue, then, in which case it should go in a new question of its own.

Comment: Changed the data manually into Date format from excel,@AMC thanks for the guidelines will take care,but none of your comments have actually helped in sorting the issue., I feel issue is still with the dates here, hence can be continued on the same thread

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is excel.
Excel likes to show dates as Month-Day for some reason.

Try changing the date format to short date in excel then save and run your python script again.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Pandas is not recognizing the date format by default. You can instruct Pandas to use a custom date parser. See the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) for more details.

In your case, it would look something like this:

```
def parse_custom_date(x):
    return pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%b-%y')

data_copy = pd.read_excel(
  'D:\DS\DATA.xls', 
  'CHI', 
   index='Month', 
   parse_dates=['Month'], 
   date_parser=parse_custom_date,
)
```

Note that your date format does not appear to have day of the month, so this would assume the first day of the month.

Comment: Looks like the date format has now changed in the question, so my strptime command will no longer work. Try using the link I posted to create a matching format string, and see if that helps.